# Animating a model in SCNScene using SCNMorpher

Tags: animation, scenekit

I have an SCNNode that I've created from a custom model mesh and a SCNGeometry.  This custom model also includes a set of animations in the form of vertex target frames that I've converted into an NSArray of SCNGeometry.

I'd like to now animate the parent node using the set of SCNGeometry as frames (all SCNGeometry have the exact same number of vertices), and it appears that SCNMorpher is the correct class to handle this. However, the documentation on Apple's site for SCNMorpher gives no explanation on how to use it.

How can I animate a node using SCNMorpher and an array of SCNGeometry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `N` geometries then choose one arbitrarily and set it to your node's `geometry` property.

Then create a `SCNMorpher` and set its `targets` to an array containing the `N - 1` geometries left. Assign the morpher to the node's `morpher` property.

The default `calculationMode` is `SCNMorpherCalculationModeNormalized` and that's what you want. Finally use a Core Animation animation to animate your weights (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMorpher_Class/index.html) for an example).